# animation-helper doesn't remove animate class

Tags: javascript, meteor

html file

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
  <h1>Todo List</h1>
</header>
<div class='title'>Test</div>
  {{#Animate}}
          {{> Template.dynamic template=template_name }}
   {{/Animate}}

</div> 

</body>


<template  name="app">
  <div id='albumholder' class='albumholder animate'>
    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

css

```
.albumholder {
   opacity: 1; // value after the animate class got removed
   transition: opacity 200ms;
}

.albumholder.animate {
   opacity: 0; // initial value
}
```

https://atmospherejs.com/frozeman/animation-helper

I'm using this package to try to add animations to my app, however this animate class just stays on the div the entire time and i cant see anything inside the divs.  Any body have any suggestions on how to resolve why my animations aren't working?

```
Template.body.rendered = function () {
  controller = new SwipeController(150);
  Session.setDefault("templateName", "app");

}
```

As soon as the body renders I set the templateName so that it opens my app on the right page but Im not seeing any transition into it.

Comment: Could you add your JS helpers? I'm not certain, but I believe this library requires that you change something in the template after initial render, not on initial page view. For example, if the `tasks` variable changed, it might trigger an animation.

Comment: I found this error in the javascript console "The following element has no transition defined, but an "animate" class:"

Comment: It's really hard to debug without your full code.  I would post an issue on the plugin's GitHub page and see if they can be of more help: https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-animation-helper/issues